# ReactJS Virtual DOM vs Grammarly Browser Extension Detect Inputs Manipulation

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So, I have run across an issue where due to maintaining a state for an input field; breaks the user experience of the app when they use an extension like Grammarly in their browser. Problem as I figure is since the state is immutable and Grammarly changes the DOM without triggering an change. So in that the state doesn't change, and thus the changes from Grammarly are lost, it let's say that input is part of a form, and I hit submit. The data from reacts state gets sent down, not the visual changes grammarly made.

So my overall question is.. does anyone know of a method, means, or practice I can deploy to capture instances like this and work with them properly.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for detection of external changes of the DOM nodes, and then apply them to the state like a regular input.

Re: For more information about Grammarly extension compatibility, you can check [this](https://github.com/facebook/draft-js/issues/616#issuecomment-338298041) thread.

And also, Grammarly will release developers guide in the near future.

Comment: That is awesome news look forward to doing seeing that guide, thanks for the input.